# What's the preferred way of sorting an iterable in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Here's the situation in psuedo code:**

```
{this.props.myIterable.map((iterable) => {
    return ( <div>iterable.somevalue</div> )
}).sort((a,b) => {return b - a})
```

In other words, I'm mapping over some props and appending something to the dom based on their values, which is of course standard stuff. However, the twist is that I want to sort these in a particular way so that they're appended in a particular order.

**Here's the Question:**

1) This code works, but it feels like I'm violating some React principles. Am I, or is this totally ok?

2) If this is not the recommended way of doing things, what are the alternatives? Should I write a method within the component that I use to perform this operation? Should I perform the sorting ahead of time, say, whenever I append an item to props? Or something else?

This is all pretty theoretical, but I searched around and couldn't find anything resources on this, so I would really appreciate hearing some opinions. Thanks.

edit: b - a is actually

```
return b.props.children[0].props.children[1] - a.props.children[0].props.children[1]
```

Comment: I can't believe `b - a` is a valid comparison for ReactDOM elements

Comment: @Bergi I would assume that's just a placeholder for actual logic

Comment: @Bergi edited for clarification. I'm using the props of the children being compared.

Answer (score 2):

Sort by the `somevalue` (the future children) and then map.

**Note 1:** You should try and sort the original state (when you get data from the server, set the state, etc...) before passing it. Sorting in the render method will happen on each render, and might cause performance issues.

**Note 2:** don't forget to add a unique key to each element.

```
{this.props.myIterable
  .sort((a,b) => b.somevalue - a.somevalue)
  .map((iterable) => (<div key={iterable.key}>iterable.somevalue</div>))
}
```

Comment: And be sure to add a key to the div

Comment: Thanks for the response. What's the functional difference between performing the sort before mapping?

Comment: For starters, you don't need `a.props.children[0].props.children[1]`, In addition, react works with a model, and the model changes the view. Sort the model, and not the view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sorting as part of the render is reasonable.

If there are a lot of elements, or your render function gets called a lot, this can lead to performance issues. In this case, you can either implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) (or use a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)), or you can make a new state called `sortedIterable` (or whatever) and calculate that in `getDerivedStateFromProps`. That way you only have to calculate sort once per each time the iterable changes.